# Finding this venn diagram problem difficlut to visualize

Tags: discrete-mathematics

300 employees are selected at random for a survey. 48 employees commute by bus, 120 employees commute by subway, 84 employees drive their cars to work, and the remaining employees walk to work Out of them. 32 employees take either the bus or the subway 23 employees take either the subway or their car, and 18 employees take either their car or the bus. 8 employees.commute by all three means How many employees take either the subway or their car but not the bus?

I am not able to understand what does `either the bus or subway` means.Does it mean union because usually it is `A intersection B` in these kind of problems.

Comment: Bus and Subway is two transportation systems.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne No what I meant was this is of the form ```A U B``` since OR is used, but usually in these problems ```A intersection B``` is used

Comment: @Xtense  In such kind of problems they can ask for  every valid set they want. Suppose that $S, C, B$ denotes the sets for employees who takes the subway, car and bus. Then 

$$S\cap C\cap \overline B=(S\cup C \cup B)-B-(S\cap B)-(C\cap B)-(S\cap C\cap  B)$$ Make a Venn-diagram.

Comment: In this case, saying that a person commutes by bus or subway means that she or he should be counted as both a person who commutes by bus and a person who commutes by subway.  The reason for the use of the word or is that a person cannot simultaneously ride a bus and a subway.

Comment: @callculus42 I don't understand your answer.First of all you are not counting the remaining students who walk, and the answer should be a subset of ```employees who take subway or car``` but by your logic.its coming out to be 194 which is much higher than that.Kindly explain properly

Comment: @Xtense Yes, I've forgotten the people, who walk. Nevertheless Show us your Venn-diagram.